# Selenium/Python WebElement.send_keys is not taking the full char sequence

Tags: python, selenium

Below does not take the entire char sequence

driver.find(css=text_area).send_keys("ABCDEF")

i.e. - Only "CDEF" appears in the text area. Full char sequence is not taken.

Comment: which driver are you using? and if it's a browser, is there any sort of javascript involved with the element you're interacting with?

Comment: I'm using chromedriver and no javascript involved.

Comment: That's odd, and it's just a plain text field?

Comment: Well, JS triggers when the Keys.RETURN is sent after filling up the text area. It's also careful enough to wait until the element is completely displayed. Furthermore, I manually did a sleep to make sure that the area is displayed fully by the time the sequence is sent.

Comment: Avoid manual sleeps, use webdriver waits.  The core Python Selenium bindings are not bugged, so my only guess is there is some issue with immediately inputting text after the initial focus. If that's the case, you could consider using an Actions builder or ExecuteScript

Comment: Worked fine with WebDriverWait. Thanks John!!!